# Check SQL database if value exists and then return value if it does

Tags: php, sql, database, passwords

I am pretty new to both php and SQL.  I have a login page where I ask for the users username and password.  I would like to search a database I have created for both the username and password to see if they exist.  The database table has two columns, Username and Password.  I don't care to much about security so a simple script will work. But I do want to be able to expand on it someday, so therefor I am using a database, because currently I just use an array in php to store usernames and passwords.

I am currently trying to get this code to work but am not getting the results I need.

```
$user_name = "db_username";
$password = "db_password";
$database = "db_name";
$server = "db_server";



$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
$result =mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE Username = $username");
if ($result>0)

    {
        echo 'Username and Password Found'; 
    }
else
    {
    echo 'Username and Password NOT Found';
    }
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found.";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

This always returns `Username and Password Found` no matter is the username is in there or not. When printing `$result` I get `Resource id #2`.  Thank you

Comment: If (my answer fixed your problem) { can you give it the green checkmark? } else { let me know if it still doesn't work; }

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test it until this morning.  Thanks so much.  I did have to add apostrophes around the $username variable, but other than that, it works great.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll add in apostrophes and backticks to my answer for any future readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$result I think will evaluate to true even if the result set contains zero rows. It only returns boolean false on error according to the manual. Use mysql_num_rows to determine if you actually found anything with the query.

```
if ($db_found) {
$result =mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE `Username` = '$username'");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

    {
        echo 'Username and Password Found'; 
    }
else
    {
    echo 'Username and Password NOT Found';
    }
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found.";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

EDIT:
Of course, as of now (November 2013, and since long ago), the mysql_* functions have indeed been deprecated. Apparently you can now use identical mysqli_* functions (maybe just use find/replace), but most people are using PDO.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for your SQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE Username = " . mysql_real_escape_string($username));
```

Note: You should consider using [PDO](http://us.php.net/pdo).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() (which requires an open connection to the database) should be used instead of mysql_escape_string(). I don't know what you mean by "mysql interface" being deprecated...

Comment: @ButtleButkus: You are correct, I read the deprecation message and thought it referred to the entire mysql_* library. Updated post.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$user=$_POST["user"];
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "interior_design";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($dbname,$db_handle);
if($db_found)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ssn,fname FROM admin WHERE ssn='$pass' and fname='$user'");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo 'Username and Password Found'; 
    //header( 'Location: index.html' ) ;

    }
else
    {
    echo 'Username and Password NOT Found';
    echo $pass;
    echo $user;``
    }
}

else{
echo 'db nt found';   

mysql_close($db_hanle);
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="login.html"><h2>LOGIN</h2></a>
</body>
</html>
```